# Using a List in JqGrid Treegrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

i'm currently trying to pass a json from the controller to the jqgrid tree. I am able to show the tree properly if I use a JSON String embeded in a javascript variable like below :

```
var TagsJson=
                [
                   {
                       "id": "1","elementName": "Category: Arms/Pods", level:"0", parent:"", isLeaf:false, expanded:true, loaded:true
                   },
                   {
                       "id": "1_1","elementName": "AP | Active Pod Count (On an Arm)", level: "1", parent: "1", isLeaf: true, expanded: true, loaded: true
                   },
```

Where the View :

```
 grid.jqGrid({
            datastr: TagsJson,
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            mtype : 'POST',
            height: "auto",
            loadui: "disable",
            colNames: ["Tag | Description"],
            colModel: [
                {name: "elementName", width:250, resizable: false}
            ],
            treeGrid: true,
            treeGridModel: "adjacency",
            ExpandColumn: "elementName",
            rowNum: 10000,
            treeIcons: {leaf:'ui-icon-document-b'},
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function (obj) { return obj; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
            }
        });
```

What I want now is to use the Controller to pass the data instead of being hardcoded to the variable:

My Controller :

```
public JsonResult GetSpTreeJson()       
 {

        var TagsJson = new
        {
            total = 1,
            page = 1,
            records = 2,
            rows = new[]
            {
                new {id = 1, cell = new object[] {"1", "root 1", "0", "1", false, true, true}},
                new {id = 11, cell = new object[] {"11", "child 11", "1", "1", true, true, true}}
            }
        };

        return Json(TagsJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

I have modified the View to get the json from the controller but nothing happens, no data is displayed on the grid but in debug mode there is data from the controller, below is edited View, What am I doing wrong?

```
 grid.jqGrid({
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            url: '/Demo/GetSpTreeJson/',
            colNames: ["Tag | Description"],
            colModel: [
                {name: "elementName", width:250, resizable: false}
            ],
            treeGrid: true,
            treeGridModel: "adjacency",
            ExpandColumn: "elementName",
            rowNum: 10000,
            treeIcons: {leaf:'ui-icon-document-b'},
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function (obj) { return obj; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
            },
            pager: "#list2",
        caption: "Objects"

        });
```

Comment: Do you solved the problem already? Which version of free jqGrid you use? By the way the format of JSON data returned from `GetSpTreeJson` is quite different from the format of `TagsJson`, which you included above. Why you don't use the same format with named properties?

Comment: @Oleg, what format should it be coming from the controller? Can I ask you to give me a sample? Thanks in advance!